# Google Sheets Script get a chart's labels?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So, I have a sheet that covers a year of data, and a bar chart that updates on a trigger to show each month's data specifically.  It also sets a color for each of the bars when it updates.  The problem is that the way I did the color changing, it always has the same color in each position regardless of what the label for the bar is. (ie. if it's sorted by descending value, if X has the lowest number it's blue, and Y is second and red, etc. Then the next month Y has less so it's first and blue, and X is red).  I need to set the colors based on the label (so X is blue regardless of if it has more or less than Y in a given month).  I can't figure out how to reference what the labels are to set the colors though.

My code to update the chart and set the colors is:

```
function updateRangeBar(sheet, range, chart)
{
  
  chart = chart.modify()
    .clearRanges()
    .addRange(range)
    .setOption('series.0.items.0.color', "red")
    .setOption('series.0.items.1.color', "blue")
    .setOption('series.0.items.2.color', "yellow")
    .setOption('series.0.items.3.color', "green")
    .setOption('series.0.items.4.color', "orange")
    .setOption('series.0.items.5.color', "black")
    .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart); 
}
```

What I'm imagining the code to look like would be like

```
function updateRangeBar(sheet, range, chart)
{
  var redIndex, blueIndex, yellowIndex, greenIndex, orangeIndex, blackIndex
  for(i = 0; i < [chartBarItemsLength]; i++)
  {
    if([chartBarItemLabel] == "DataHeaderForRed")
    {
       redIndex = i
    }
    elseIf([chartBarItemLabel] == "DataHeaderForBlue")
    {
       blueIndex = i
    }
  }
  
  chart = chart.modify()
    .clearRanges()
    .addRange(range)
    .setOption('series.0.items.'+redIndex+'.color', "red")
    .setOption('series.0.items.'+blueIndex'+.color', "blue")
    .setOption('series.0.items.+yellowIndex'+.color', "yellow")
    .setOption('series.0.items.+greenIndex'+.color', "green")
    .setOption('series.0.items.+orangeIndex'+.color', "orange")
    .setOption('series.0.items.+blackIndex'+.color', "black")
    .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart); 
}
```

Where [chartBarItemLabel] and [chartBarItemsLength] are what I need help finding a way to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an answer, though better options would always be nice.

```
function updateRangeBar(sheet, range, chart)
{
 
  var subRange = range.getSheet().getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn(), range.getHeight(), 1)
  chart = chart.modify()
    .clearRanges()
    .addRange(range)
    .build()
  for(i = 0; i < subRange.getHeight(); i++)
  {
    var val = range.getSheet().getRange((subRange.getRow()+(i+1)), subRange.getColumn()).getValue()
      
      if(val.toString() == BLUE_TYPE)
      {
        chart = chart.modify().setOption('series.0.items.'+i+'.color', BLUE_RGB).build()
      }
      else if(val.toString() == RED_TYPE)
      {
        chart = chart.modify().setOption('series.0.items.'+i+'.color', RED_RGB).build()
      }
      else if(
      ...
  }
  sheet.updateChart(chart); 
}
```

Comment: Please, consider adding extra comments to allow other users to better understand your answer

Comment: Could you explain what you think needs comments?  I can add them, i just need to know what would be good to comment for this